# insert a many to many relationship in xcode 4.2 using coredata

Tags: core-data, insert, many-to-many, xcode4.2

Hi Im trying to insert a many to many relationship but fails =(

here is the code

categoria.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class SubCategoria;

@interface Categoria : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nombre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *subcategoria;
@end

@interface Categoria (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addSubcategoriaObject:(SubCategoria *)value;
- (void)removeSubcategoriaObject:(SubCategoria *)value;
- (void)addSubcategoria:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSubcategoria:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

categoria.m

```
#import "Categoria.h"
#import "SubCategoria.h"


@implementation Categoria

@dynamic id;
@dynamic nombre;
@dynamic subcategoria;

@end
```

Then I try to insert in the following way.

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Categoria *cat = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categoria" 
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

    cat.id =[NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    cat.nombre = @"portatil";




    SubCategoria *subCat =  [NSEntityDescription
                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SubCategoria" 
                             inManagedObjectContext:context];
    subCat.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    subCat.nombre = @"toshiba";

    SubCategoria *subCat2 = [NSEntityDescription
                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SubCategoria" 
                             inManagedObjectContext:context];

    subCat2.id =[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    subCat2.nombre = @"sony";



    [cat addSubcategoriaObject:subCat];


     [cat addSubcategoriaObject:subCat2];

  NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

It insert the categories and subcategories but when it tries to insert the relation ship give me this exception.

```
 -[Categoria subcategoria]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6dd8290
```

Why is this error happening ?????
Thanks soo much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `Categoria` entity doesn't have a `subcategoria` property. Double check your model. Maybe you mistyped something.

In your code, what does

```
NSLog(@"%@", cat);
```

output?

Comment: Hey, I fix the problem, dont know really how actually but I suspect that in the relation ship many to many I didnt check the cascade field (I know that doesn't make that much sence since is a cascade for delete). Any ways is working, maybe i just had to regenerate de model. But thanks a lot